# Send JSON Request to server issue: android

Tags: android

Issue in sending JSON request

```
{
 clickInformation:

 previousPageID:none,
 previousPageName:none
 },
```

Comment: this is not a valid json

Comment: "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method." is this a server issue, ie. A server configuration issue?

Comment: try to validate the json first: http://jsonlint.com/
You are using strings without quotes...

Comment: @Wizche *and* keys without values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below modified String,

```
 String newdata= "'clickInformation':{"+"'clickName':"+"'login_page'"+","+
```

put **(' ')** before and after any key or value of your JSON.

might this will help you. 
If it is useful to you than don't forgot to accept this as a answer and upvote.